# передать значение,полученное bat файлом в питоновский скрипт

Tags: python, bat

Пытаюсь перебросить значение,полученное bat файлом и сохраненным как "find_folder" в скрипт питона, но никак не получается код bat файла:

```
set find_folder = %1;
% python find.py %find_folder
```

код find.py:

```
import sys;
name_folder = sys.argv[1];
print(name_folder);
```

из командной строки:

`Naz.bat hello`

ошибки:
"find_folder" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Подскажите,что не так делаю.Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
set find_folder=%1;
python find.py %find_folder%
```

Тогда, из скрипта значение `find_folder` также можно будет получить из переменных окружения:

```
import sys
import os
print(sys.argv[1], os.environ.get('find_folder'))
```

А если просто передать аргумент, то достаточно:

```
python find.py %1
```

Comment: ,к сожалению,та же ошибка(

Comment: @ЕвгенийНазарук, обновил ответ

Comment: Cпасибо большое. А подскажите, в чем разница "python find.py %find_folder%" от "% python find.py %find_folder%?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНазарук, по моему, второй вариант просто синтаксически неправильный, но могу ошибаться -- с батниками почти не работаю. А [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)